# Конструктор базового класса

Tags: c++

Как в конструкторе базового класса узнать, создаётся именно объект базового класса или производного?

Нужно для того, чтобы иметь `static` вектор указателей на базовый класс на все ранее созданные объекты. Т.к. при создании объекта вызывается конструктор базового класса, в вектор попадают лишние указатели, поэтому нужно либо очищать его от этих указателей после очередного добавления, либо перед добавлением проверять на предмет вопроса.

Comment: Похоже, что вы городите какой-то костыль. Как только появляются статические глобальные сущности, программист приобретает огромное количество проблем.

Comment: @gbg а как иначе иметь доступ ко всем ранее созданным объектам?

Comment: Есть такой классный паттерн - фабрика классов. Как насчет его внедрения?

Comment: @gbg думаю, это усложнит понимание программы, но если не будет подходящего ответа, то придётся внедрять

Comment: Понимание программы как раз усложнит глобальная сущность и костыли вокруг конструкторов. Паттерн с фабрикой знают все программисты, ваш велосипед - только вы.

Comment: @gbg: Не заметил ваш комментарий. У меня в ответе как раз фабрика.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Как в конструкторе базового класса узнать, создаётся именно объект базового класса или производного?*

В конструкторе базового класса создается **исключительно** объект базового класса. Другое дело, что он может быть *частью* объекта-наследника.

Непосредственного способа не вижу; я бы - если так уж приспичило - сделал бы специальный конструктор с фиктивным параметром, объявленный как `prootected` - чтоб никто не мог напрямую вызвать - и вызывал в производном классе именно его. Это и было бы указанием на то, что данный конструктор - часть создания объекта производного класса.

Примерно так:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() { /* ... */ }
protected:
    class ForDerived {};
    Base(ForDerived) { /* только из потомков */ }
    //
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived():Base(Base::ForDerived()) { }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

До данного ответа идею с фабрикой выдвинул @gbg в комментариях, так что пальма первенства принадлежит по праву ему.

---

Правильный подход в этом случае такой: спрятать конструктор и конструировать объекты через фабрику. В конструкторе у вас слишком мало контроля, а вот с фабрикой как раз вы получаете полный контроль и простор для дальнейшего произвольного усложнения логики программы.

Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
    friend class Factory;
protected:
    Base() { cout << "Base constructed" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    friend class Factory;
protected:
    Derived() { cout << "Derived constructed" << endl; }
};

vector<shared_ptr<Base>> all_base_pointers;

class Factory
{
public:
    static shared_ptr<Base> Construct()
    {
        static int alloc_no = 0;
        if (alloc_no++ % 2 == 0)
            return ConstructBase();
        else
            return ConstructDerived();
    }
private:
    static shared_ptr<Base> ConstructBase()
    {
        shared_ptr<Base> p(new Base());
        all_base_pointers.push_back(p);
        return p;
    }

    static shared_ptr<Base> ConstructDerived()
    {
        shared_ptr<Base> p(new Derived());
        return p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto p1 = Factory::Construct(), p2 = Factory::Construct(), p3 = Factory::Construct();
    cout << "constructed " << all_base_pointers.size() << " base instances" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы:

> Base constructed
>   Base constructed
>   Derived constructed
>   Base constructed
>   constructed 2 base instances